# Как показать изображение над FrameLayout?

Tags: java, android

Дело в том, что я хочу показать картинку над видеоплеером. Видеоплеер во фрагменте, а фрагмент вызывается в `MainActivity`, а в `main_layout.xml` находится сам `FrameLayout` во весь экран для плеера и над ним `ImageView`. Не работает, то есть плеер играет но самой картинки нет.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Попробовал еще вместо вызова `Fragment` в `MainActivty` использовать компонент `Fragment` и в xml прописать класс фрагмента, плеер работает опять же без картинки.
Даже попробовал картинку вставить в разметке самого плеера все равно не видит.

Вопрос: что я не так делаю?

Использую библиотеку [JieCaoVideoPlayer](https://github.com/lipangit/JieCaoVideoPlayer)

Comment: Может попробовать стандартный способ проставления картинки вместо `app:srcCompat`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо помогло!!!

Comment: Написал в ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае ошибка в том, что вы используете не тот атрибут для указания какую картинку отображать. Замените

> app:srcCompat

на

```
android:src
```

Comment: Но интересно, в чем отличия?

Comment: @TITAN, если не ошибаюсь, то ваш способ - это наследие попытки отображения векторых картинок в одной из уже старых версий либ поддержки. После отображение векторов настроили нормально и этот атрибут уже не нужен

Answer (score 0):

У RelativeLayout вьюшки всегда на одном уровне. Попробуйте ImageView сделать выше в иерархии, чем FrameLayout, т.е например вложить в LinearLayout

т.е

```
<RelativeLayout>
...
    <FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView> 
        </ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```